How to Remove Preferred Languages from Microsoft Edge using PowerShell
I am trying to manage the preferred languages in my Microsoft Edge browser on Windows using PowerShell. Specifically, I want to remove certain languages that appear in the "edge://settings/languages" settings (e.g., Dutch).

To do this, I need to know which registry keys or paths in HKLM and/or HKCU I can target for removal. I plan to use the Remove-Item cmdlet in PowerShell to delete these registry entries.
For example, the PowerShell command I plan to use is:
Remove-Item -Path <registryPath> -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop

Could anyone guide me on the exact registry keys or paths that correspond to the preferred languages settings in Microsoft Edge? Any assistance on how to identify and remove these entries correctly would be greatly appreciated.
P.S. I wonder if this setting is not stored in the registry but maybe in the C:\Users\$Env:UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Preferences JSON file. 
P.S.2. I also posted this question here on Discord and here on Microsoft TechCommunity.
P.S.3. I asked a follow-up question here.

@Gantendo because I want to automate it and not think about it again.

There is an Edge policy setting to define these. Normally, it's easiest to configure this using GPO or Intune policies, but you can set it locally with powershell too:
# HKLM=system-wide, HKCU=per-user
New-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\' `
  -Name DefinePreferredLanguages `
  -PropertyType REG_SZ `
  -Value "en-US,fr,es"

Note: this policy is Mandatory if set, so end users cannot change it
You can check whether it's been applied by going to about://policy in Edge
Microsoft Edge policy documentation
Supported language codes

Thanks for the comment. AS was also discussed here on Discord; I added this key manually, yet the languages remain after restarting the Edge browser.

@Foad does anything show up in the about://policy page? This policy should override the user-defined preferences if it applied properly (and didn't get removed/overwritten by a domain policy or something)

@Foad - I don't have Discord.  Relevant information should be included in the body of the question. Information on Discord is not guaranteed to exist tommorow.

@Ramhound, thanks for the comment. I understand your point, though all the necessary information was already in the comment and the original post. The link to the Discord discussion was for those who are interested in following the discussion.

When I ran your initial command in an elevated PowerShell terminal, I got this error, so I changed it to New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\' -Name DefinePreferredLanguages -PropertyType String -Value "en-US" then I got this error telling me that this property already exists, as I had added it yesterday manually.

Checking the about://policy page (screenshot), I see that the DefinePreferredLanguages is now there, but the unwanted languages are still in the Preferred Languages list, as seen in the screenshot shown in the original post.

@Foad the screenshot of your policy page shows the DefinePreferredLanguages setting has a Status of Ignored (along with many others). If you are signed into a personal Microsoft account, certain GPOs are now ignored due to Edge for Business.

@Cpt.Whale, is there a way to force this specific Group Policy Object (GPO) not to be ignored? This is really annoying!

@Foad Does Edge show a "personal" account is logged in? If so, you can use the Restrict which accounts can be used to sign into Microsoft Edge setting to specify which domain's users can log in (and it doesn't have to be real - policies also work if you are not signed in at all). Otherwise, if you click the Show More in your screenshot, then it may have a different reason like having an invalid value instead

@Cpt.Whale, I am not sure if I follow your points. This particular Edge browser is indeed for my personal Microsoft account. I do have full admin rights on this computer.

@Foad ah, then unfortunately you cannot use these policies (they are designed around a byod style where company policies don't step on other stuff). If you're using a personal account, then language preferences should sync to that account anyways

I did a quick check with procmon, and I see that changing the preferred language list only updates a registry value here: HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Spelling\Dictionaries\ named _Global_ (it looks like more of a MS Office integration though). These preferences are likely stored in the chromium user profile sqlite database - that can be edited too, but I haven't messed with it myself

I asked a follow-up question here
